# Trying to create a game with a countdown which resets the countdown once a particular button is clicked

Tags: python, countdown

So im trying to create a game with a countdown which resets the countdown once a particular  button is clicked basically if the player plays his move. but im not able to code the re-setting part of the countdown. it would be great if anyone could help.

**button :**

```
rock = Button(
    input_frame, 
    pady = 5, 
    text = 'Rock', 
    width = 15, 
    bg = 'pink',
    command = lambda: [player_choice(options[0]), countdown]
)
rock.grid(row = 1, column = 1,padx = 8, pady = 5)

paper = Button(input_frame, 
    pady = 5,
    text = 'Paper',
    width = 15,
    bg = 'silver',
    command = lambda: [player_choice(options[1]),countdown]
)
paper.grid(row = 1, column = 2,padx = 8,pady=1)

scissors = Button(input_frame, 
    pady = 5, 
    text = 'Scissors', 
    width = 15,
    bg = 'light blue',
    command = lambda: [player_choice(options[2]),countdown]
)
scissors.grid(row = 1, column = 3,padx = 8, pady = 5)
```

**countdown code**

```
t=10
def countdown():
    global t, computer_score
    if t > 0:
        print(t)
        timer.config(text=t)
        t = t - 1
        timer.after(1000, countdown)
    elif t == 0:
        timer.config(text='00')
        winner.config(text="TIMES UP !! Computer Won !!")
        computer_score += 1
        comp_score.config(text='Your Score : ' + str(computer_score))
        if str(comp_score) > str(your_score):
            champ = str('COMPUTER')
        elif comp_score == your_score:
            champ = str('TIE')
        else:
            champ = str('YOU')
        win.config(text='Winner : ' + str(champ), font=('calibri',15), fg='red')
```

Comment: Can you explain your code a little better?

Comment: If you could explain exactly what you're struggling with, you'll be more likely to get helpful responses. Please also do read the guidelines on how to write a minimal, reproducible example. Currently, it's impossible for us to try out your code for numerous reasons. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Also you dont have to do type conversion each time you use a new variable or old in Python, i.e. do this: `champ = str('TIE')`, just `champ = 'TIE'` is enough